# show modal popup from code behind

Tags: modalpopupextender

i have a dropdownlist

in codebehind,i have this function

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///////
}
```

now i want to show modal popup when a particular text is selected from the dropdownlist from this function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Some Text"))
{
     ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```